# Is there a way to bypass mod_auth_openidc module used in an Apache Web Server for some users/IP ranges/service-calls?

Tags: apache, webserver, reverse-proxy, openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc

For a web app, we have used an Apache Web Server with mod_auth_openidc module as an authentication layer; it sits in front of our web app.

There's a requirement to let requests from some services (eg. a web crawler, to crawl the web app) to bypass this OIDC layer.
Is there a way to add this override or bypass mod_auth_openidc for request from some users, services, or maybe even an IP range?

I've tried to look around in the [list](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/auth_openidc.conf) of configuration options, but couldn't find any config that does that, yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the standard `<If>` directive - see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if - with expression matching of some header/ip as described in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html so, e.g:

```
<If "-R '192.168.1.0/24'">
    Require ip 192.168.1.1
</If>
<Else>
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require valid-user
</Else>
```

Be aware that header spoofing is easy though, local IP matching is probably the safest choice.